# Why pulling the measures into browser doesn't show even if the resultset has values?

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

While processing an SSAS cube, the query that I got from processing window like "under SQL queries 1" is producing resultset, but when the processing is done and the measures are pulled into the browser, the values do not show up.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have a default member set on some dimension that's filtering out results. Ensure that all of your dimensions are at the "All" level, and that your measure is additive in some way.